# Setting up OpenCV 2.4.3 & Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 ( Win8 x64 )

Tags: opencv, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I want to configure **opencv** with **Visual Studio 2012** on **Windows 8 x64**.
I configured **opencv** and there is no compilation errors, but when I execute my program I get this error :

> The program can’t start because **MSVCR100D.dll** is missing from your
>   computer

I tried to install **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012** and **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)** but always the same error.

Answer (score 4):

If it's still relevant, try this tutorial to create project and configure OpenCV directories:

http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/

It worked for me on Windows 8 (x64) with Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCV 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

After configuring the paths and libraries in Visual Studio as mentioned in http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/ you need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

After restarting your PC, opencv code could be executed in Release mode. If you need to execute the code in Debug mode, then you would have to install the Redistributable version with "D".

This worked with Opencv 2.4.6, Windows 8.1 and VS 2012 Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Without having any experience with Windows 8 myself, I think [this](http://villavu.com/forum/showthread.php?t=82512) post could solve your problem.

Basically it says that the default system folder for Win 8 is c:\windows\system, unlike c:\windows\system32 on earlier systems. The redistributables probably install to the old system directory, so you have to move the dll to the correct folder manually.

You could also search the file on your PC and put it into the working folder of your program. This is in most cases the output folder, if you run it in Debug mode from VS it can also be the project folder.

Comment: I tried to copy **MSVCR100.dll** from **c:\windows\system32** to **c:\windows\system** but always the same error. I found **MSVCR100.dll** on my PC but not **MSVCR100D.dll**

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2753/msvcr100ddll-is-missing-opencv-242-visualstudio/) thread. With a little Googling you probably would have gottan a quicker answer. I searched for "visual studio 2012 msvcr100d", the first two results answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still have the same error, I copied msvcp100.dll, msvcp110d.dll from `C:\Windows\System32` to `\Debug` folder and I got a new error : `the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library opencv ..`. I'm gonna switch to **Codeblocks**. Apparently **Codeblocks** Works Fine with **Opencv**.