# openCV 2.4.9 compatibility with Windows 8

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

after compiling my opencv program on visual studio 12, while running it from the debug folder i am getting an error message saying that openCV 2.4.9 is not designed for windows 8

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the prebuilt libraries? If Yes then compile them yourself on the Windows 8 Platform.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569757/setting-up-opencv-2-4-3-microsoft-visual-studio-2012-win8-x64) SO Question & Answer set will help you.